# Scrollview alignment

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have the following:

[image]

```
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {

                ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {

                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 30) {
                        ForEach(0 ..< meals.count) { count in
                            HStack(alignment: .center,spacing: 120){
                                VStack{
                                    Text("\(count + 1) ")
                                    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                                    .padding(.horizontal, 8)
                                    .padding(.vertical, 5)
                                    .background(
                                        Capsule()
                                            .fill(Color.black)
                                            .opacity(0.20)
                                    )
                                }

                                VStack{
                                    Text("\(self.meals[count]) ")
                                    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                                }

                                VStack{
                                    Image(systemName: "pencil")
                                    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                                    .font(.system(size: 20))
                                    .background(Color.yellow)
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width) // set a fixed width
//                        .background(Color.green)
                }
                .frame(height: 185)
                .frame(maxWidth: 400)
                .padding(.top, -200)
            }
```

How can I make the pencil icon stay to the right? I tried putting `alignment: .trailing` on it but doesn't work.

I saw an example with geometry but then the scroll view gets weird, I need it with this. Also how can I make sure the width between the items stay the same across devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of hardcoding spacing use `Spacer()` which like spring push subviews aside.

Note: You don't need `VStack` for only one subview, so it can be removed for simplicity.

Here is resulting row:

```
HStack { // .center is by default, so also remove
    Text("\(count + 1) ")
        .foregroundColor(Color.black)
        .padding(.horizontal, 8)
        .padding(.vertical, 5)
        .background(
            Capsule()
                .fill(Color.black)
                .opacity(0.20)
        )

    Spacer()           // << here !!

    Text("\(self.meals[count]) ")
        .foregroundColor(Color.black)

    Spacer()           // << here !!

    Image(systemName: "pencil")
        .foregroundColor(Color.black)
        .font(.system(size: 20))
        .background(Color.yellow)
}
```

Comment: That's great, thanks for the right approach, but the problem is that then the letters at the middle would be centered. How can I make only the letters in the middle be aligned with .leading so they begin on the same spot but stay where they are centered? I hope you understood more or less what I was trying to say